# Skype video problem on Dell Xps 13 9350

Tags: skype, xps

Every time I skype with somebody the video is never stable, it flashes constantly with strange blue background. Secondly I don't see myself in the little rectangle at the corner, but just a zoomed part of it, although the person with whom I am speaking sees me well and has no problem with that.

I have a Dell XPS 13 (9350), i just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, before I had 15.10 and I had the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ... 
https://github.com/linuxenko/ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix
or just add

```
Section "Extensions"
        Option "XVideo" "Disable"
EndSection
```

to xorg.conf (if you have it).